# How can I solve this matrix differential equation?

Tags: matrices, ordinary-differential-equations

Given matrices $\mathbf{A}(x)$, $\mathbf{B}(x)$ and $\mathbf{C}(x)$, I want to solve:

$$ \frac{d}{dx}\mathbf{A}(x)+\mathbf{B}(x)\mathbf{A}(x)+\mathbf{A}(x)\mathbf{C}(x) = 0$$

for $\mathbf{A}(x)$ in terms of $\mathbf{B}(x)$ and $\mathbf{C}(x)$. Where multiplication is the normal matrix multiplication.

Any ideas?

With $\mathbf{C}(x)=0$ I believe there is a simple solutoin with $$\mathbf{A}(x)=e^{\int_c^x \mathbf{B}(y)dy}$$ but I'm not sure how to work out the general case.

Comment: Fixed my solution. Instead of superposition, it's the product of the two cases.

Comment: What is the structure of $A(x)$?

Answer (score 1):

Take the case where $B=0$. Then we have

$$A' = -AC \implies (A^T)' = -C^TA^T \implies A = (ke^{-\int_c^x C^T(y) dy})^T$$

for some constant $k$.

Edit: I thought about it some more and superposition doesn't work. Instead the solution is the product of the two cases:

$$A(x) = ke^{-\int_{x_0}^xB(y)dy}(e^{-\int_{x_0}^x C^T(y)dy})^T$$

which passes the sanity check of as $B$ or $C$ go to zero, their respective contributions turn into the identity matrix.